# How to assign value from one file field to another programmatically?

Tags: 7, webforms, users, files

I have a webform which have a file field. In the user profile I have also created a file field.

I am using the webform for user registration So I am assigning the values from the webform to the user profile fields programmtically on webform submit.

But I am unable assing the uploaded file in the webform to the user profile file field.

I am using the following code for assigning the file.

```
  $user->field_user_file['files']['und'][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['submitted']['field_webform_file'];
```

but it did not work.

Any Idea what should I do for this?

Comment: File upload fields don't have a value column. It's a 'fid' you should be assigning instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it. Here is the code that I used to solved the problem.

```
  $file = file_load($fid);
  $user->field_user_file = array(
    'und' => array(
      '0' => array(
        'fid' => $file->fid,
        'filename' => $file->filename,
        'filemime' => $file->filemime,
        'uri' => $file->uri,
        'status' => 1,
        'display' => 1
      )
    )
  );
```